# Store a variable in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is part of my code:

```
$("#demo").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {

  var name = countryData.name;
  var cod  = countryData.dialCode;
  var iso2 = countryData.iso2;
}); 


 $("#demo").intlTelInput({
   allowDropdown: true,
   autoHideDialCode: false,
   autoPlaceholder: "off",
   dropdownContainer: "body",
   formatOnDisplay: false,
   geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
     $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
       var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
       callback(countryCode);
     });
   },
   hiddenInput: "full_number",
   initialCountry: "auto",
   nationalMode: false,
   placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
   preferredCountries:[''],
   separateDialCode: false,
   utilsScript: "intl-tel-input-master/build/js/utils.js"
});
```

I would like to know how to store the value of variable "iso2" in that next array "preferredCountries: [' ']" ?

Comment: Well, the `$("#demo").intlTelInput({` code seems to run when the page is loaded, I think? So you passed in the `preferredCountries` array at that moment, and it's gone into whatever that plugin is. your iso2 variable doesn't seem to become available until the "countrychange" event has happened, so it seems like the moment for setting the value has already passed, I think? Perhaps this option can be updated separately within your plugin? I don't know, you didn't tell us what the plugin is so I can't check the documentation. Perhaps you can do so.

Comment: Here is the link for that plug-in:  https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html

Comment: that plug-in name is: International Telephone Input

Comment: it doesn't appear to have a public method which would allow you to alter the preferred countries after the plugin has been initialised. So I suggest that you would have to destroy and re-initialise the plugin every time your countrychange event runs, and set the new value that way. But why do you want to? The countrychange event happens on that same telephone field, yes? So the user has selected a country. Why do you need to add it to the "preferred" countries list? It will not persist next time they load the page, and they don't need to select it again...I can't see the need for it?

Comment: This is the official repository. A shame that that website just takes credit: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Comment: I want to have for preferred country the country automatically selected by the plug-in. I want to put in "preferredCountries: []" the iso2 of the automatically selected country.  SORRY for my english.

Comment: I visited here https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input but i din't find solution of my problem

Comment: I want to have for preferred country the country automatically selected (with ip adress) by the plug-in. When the user come on m'y site his country is automatically selected. Ï want to have that country in the preferred country.

Comment: Ok I see. You should have clarified that in the question. You're looking in the wrong place. You do not need to wait for the "countrychange" event in order to do that. That event runs when the user manually selects a country. Instead you can just get the IP value from wherever you get it, and place it straight into preferredCountries at startup. But again, why do you need to do this? You're already using the geoIpLookup function which will directly input the country mentioned by the user's IP as the "selected" country. Since that's already done, why do you need to "suggest" a country as well?